# Stack overflow with $.colorbox.resize

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am getting a stack overflow in Firefox and Chrome (and presumably everything else) after calling `$.colorbox.resize();`. I have narrowed the problem down to that method and without it everything runs fine, albeit the modal is the wrong size.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
d.extend.type
d.extend.makeArray
d.fn.d.init
d
g.plugins.fn.clone
a.each.a.fn.(anonymous function)
g.plugins.fn.clone
a.each.a.fn.(anonymous function)
g.plugins.fn.clone
a.each.a.fn.(anonymous function)
g.plugins.fn.clone
a.each.a.fn.(anonymous function)
g.plugins.fn.clone
a.each.a.fn.(anonymous function)
g.plugins.fn.clone
a.each.a.fn.(anonymous function)
...
```

I just created a few dynamic colorboxes in the browser's console instead of running through my usual event handlers and methods. Each time I tried to `$.colorbox.resize()` these dynamic colorboxes, I got a stack overflow. This makes me think that the error is independent of any custom code that displays and prepares the colorboxes.

I'm using jQuery 1.5.2.

Why is the stack overflow happening and how can I prevent it from happening?

**UPDATE**

And a little pseudo code for my control flow:

```
mouseClickHandler = function()
{
    async_method_1(function()
    {
        someMethod1()
    })
}

someMethod1 = function()
{
    async_method_2(function()
    {
        someMethod2()
    })
}
someMethod2 = function()
{
    $.colorbox.resize();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

As I mentioned earlier, creating the colorbox in the console apart from the above code also results in the stack overflow. For example, if I enter the following two lines into the browser's console, I still get the overflow.

```
$.colorbox({html:'<h1>hello world</h1>'})
$.colorbox.resize()
```

Comment: How is it being used in context? Some code samples?

Comment: @KyleMacey I added some pseudocode that shows the stack and how the method is being called. It is stripped down a bit for sanity's sake but all the methods that are on the stack when `$.colorbox.resize` is called are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue myself. The stack overflow was occurring because colorbox was being included on the page twice. Once I removed the second script tag, everything was peachy again.

There's no reason why anyone should need to include colorbox twice but an obscure stack overflow is not justified punishment to the poor developer that accidentally made the mistake :). I know the colorbox developer uses SO. Perhaps, he can put in a redundancy fail-safe or a `throw new Error` with a helpful message.